# nuget package inside

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I understand [how to build dll nuget package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package) 
I would like to build a JavaScript nuget package of  my own. I would like to learn how jQuery nuget package being constructed/installed by nuget.

How do I know how jQuery (or similar nuget package) nuget package being constructed? Especially I would like to know how these *.js being copied/ installed to  specific folder (scripts) of a ASP.net MVC project

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuGet uses a convention-over-configuration approach. This is what makes it easy to inject some files (images, code, javascript, etc) into a specific folder of a target Visual Studio project.

You can simply open a .nupkg file with any zip-utility (e.g. 7zip) and extract the archive to see its contents.

A NuGet package can have 3 folders: lib, content & tools.
Anything in the content folder will be injected into the target project using the same relative path to the project root as to the content folder of the nuget package.

More info here: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/package-conventions

Also with respect to how jQuery or other similar Javascript libraries are packaged, here are some pointers.

The list of public jQuery/jQuery plugins that have been "NuGetified" can be see here http://nuget.org/packages?q=jquery The jQuery NuGet package page http://nuget.org/packages/jQuery has a note saying that it is maintained by the NuGet Community Packages project.

If you go to the CodePlex project at http://nugetpackages.codeplex.com/ and browse the source code, you'll find it contains a couple of sub projects. These are NuGet package projects for the respective open source (mainly Javascript) projects.

You will notice that they simply include the relevant pure Javascript packages, e.g. jquery-1.8.3.js, jquery-1.8.3.min.js, etc. in the Content/Scripts path.